# Display issue when an iframe is embedded inside another iframe in Chrome 33

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe

We've noticed some very strange behaviour in Chrome 33 which isn't replicated in earlier versions or in other browsers.

As an example, if you visit http://www.fatface.com/ and click on the Lace Jumper the content is cut off once you start scrolling down. 
This overlay window is an iframe and sometimes content is pulled in again into an iframe (You Tube videos/Review forms etc) Content will display fine unless there is already an embedded iframe present or if by hitting a 'Write a Review' link to pull in an embedded iframe.

Has anybody come across this issue or got an idea for a fix?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen, please try to make substantive edits. Improve the content by fixing mistakes, and make sure **your** improvement is grammatically correct

Comment: @IvayloSlavov Yes i will look after it. I thought he referred individual.